# OpenSearch return results based on field in multiple indices

Tags: opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I have an index containing vulnerable dependencies, and their status in repositories.
I don't want to remove the alerts when they are resolved, as i also want to log that the vulnerability has been patched.

However, this means that i end up with some data that i'm not sure what would be the best way to deal with.

Here is a simplified example of how my data looks like

| _id | alert_id | repository | alert_name | action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | car_repository | jwt | created |
| 2 | 2 | car_repository | express | created |
| 3 | 2 | car_repository | express | *resolved* |
| 4 | 5 | boat_repository | express | created |
| 5 | 3 | car_repository | log4j | *resolved* |
| 6 | 3 | car_repository | log4j | created |
| 7 | 4 | boat_repository | log4j | created |

In total, 5 vulnerability warnings has been created. 2 of them has been resolved.
Now - what i want to do is show the current status. We have 3 active vulnerabilities still. How would i go about only showing the 3 relevant rows? (1, 4 and 7)

Keep in mind that i am still pretty new to using ELK/OpenStack, so i don't know if this is best solved using queries or filters, or if it would help dividing into multiple indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the easiest way would be to maintain 2 indices: one for `actions` with what you have in the table above and one with `vulnerabilities` and *current* status. So whenever you're creating a `"created"` action you would also create a vulnerability doc with `status == "created"` and when you create action which is not `"created"` you'll [update_by_query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) that doc to set `status = "resolved"`. Then your query would become super simple.

Alternative would be to use [collapse](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/collapse-search-results.html) but in my experience its behavior is quite confusing when you try to paginate or aggregate the results.